# StencilJS: Why are all the icons imported at compile time when I am only getting a single icon?

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, tree-shaking

I have an `icons.js` file which contains icon objects (objects with properties of an icon). In that file, I export a simple getter function which returns the requested icon. I then have an icon component, which imports that getter function, and invokes it with the string of the requested icon passed to it as a Prop.

Here's the getter function inside my `icons.js`:

```js
const getIcon = (icon) => icons[icon];
```

This is the only thing that's exported from the `icons.js` file.

Inside my icon component, I import the getter function, and pass to it the name of the string:

```js
getIcon(this.icon);
```

`this.icon` is a Prop used to pass the name of the icon as a string when using the icon component.

This is the essence of the structure of the project.

Now, the question is, when the app is compiled, will all of the icons be imported and compiled too? I was told that all the icons will be imported this way, which will make the app more heavy, and to enable "tree shaking". The solution is to only import the icon you need, which means the icon component cannot be dynamic.

My question is, isn't the only way to NOT import all the icons on compile time to not use an `icons.js` file, but to directly get the icon from an external source? In that case, the importation cannot be dynamic, right?

Second question is, is importing all the icons really that big of an issue? We only have about 200KB worth of icons.

Comment: _" I was told that all the icons will be imported"_ Then ask the people who told you what is wrong. Your current question is kinda like asking "My car doesn't drive", and showing us nothing but the ignition key

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman The question is not about something being wrong or not working, it's about how things work. On compile time, when you want to deploy your app, any referenced file will get compiled, and then downloaded. So, if you only use 1 icon, but you reference the entire file with icons, all of them will get compiled, and then downloaded, that was the question. Is this a problem in terms of performance, and how can or should it be avoided?